# Using regex to match date format but without square brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, datepicker, capturing-group

[image]

This is what I have. I only want to match date format `YYYY-MM-DD` or `{{variable-name}}=YYYY-MM-DD` which in **square brackets**. I tried to use the following regex:

This regex for **YYYY-MM-DD** format:

```
(\[[\d-]*\])
```

This accepts **{{variable-name}}=YYYY-MM-DD** pattern:

```
(\[{{[\w-_]*}}=[\d-]+\])
```

These regular expressions are matched date format and square brackets, however, I want to remove square brackets at the same time. How can I excluded square brackets with the non-capturing group (`?:`).

Test this expression here: [**regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/jocLVP/1)

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't this just what you want ? [`\[([\d-]*)\]|\[({{[\w-_]*}}=[\d-]+)\]`](https://regex101.com/r/jocLVP/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you want :

- Matching the square brackets but not capturing them :

  `\[([\d-]*)\]|\[({{[\w-_]*}}=[\d-]+)\]`

[See demo.](https://regex101.com/r/jocLVP/2)

- Not matching the brackets :

  `(?<=\[)([\d-]*)(?=\])|(?<=\[)({{[\w-_]*}}=[\d-]+)(?=\])`

[See other demo.](https://regex101.com/r/xeUoyg/2)

Comment: Thanks to @Paul-Etienne, the second one works just as expected, but the `[` is redundancy in your `(?<=\[)([[\d-]*)(?=\])`.

Comment: You're right, I missed it trying multiple regex. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

```
 use this RegEX
((?!\[)[\d\-]+(?=\]))|((?!\[){{[\w-_]*}}=[\d-]+(?=\]))
```

https://regex101.com/r/jocLVP/3

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked when I tested in regex101.